# Getting an error from the application when recording a Jmeter test plan

Tags: jmeter

When I am running the recorder through Jmeter and then start going through the application and try to upload a file, after the upload is done but not really loaded I am then prompted for the title and description of the media.   But after I click submit I get the error from the application that the file type is not supported.  However following those exact same steps manually I am able to upload successfully without any errors.    Can someone let me know what I am missing??  I am just starting to play with Jmeter so this is all new to me.   Thanks.

Here are some screen recordings:
http://screencast.com/t/20N8hEpmDSH  - recording application with Jmeter

http://screencast.com/t/aEFKNuArrr   - uploading file without recording using Jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should put the file, you're trying to upload to the JMeter's "bin" folder, JMeter's proxy isn't able to locate it in the "Downloads" folder. Alternative possible location is your desktop, however it depends on how do you launch JMeter, I need to see the log file to tell for sure. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation.

Few other advices:

- If you add [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to your WorkBench/Test Plan you will get way more detailed information on what is going on
- You can get JMeter ready for recording in a couple of clicks using [Templates](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#template) feature.

Comment: As soon as I can accept the answer (which I believe is tomorrow) I will check it off.    :)